Org mode Sort region/ children sort order has changed
in my org file I declare:
#+PRIORITIES: 0 9 9
Say I have a list of sub-headings:
TODO [#0] Bob 
TODO Tim
TODO [#1] Percival

I was until recently using emacs 26.1 with org mode 9.1.9.
If I did a Sort region/ children C-c ^ [p]riority on the parent heading I would get:
TODO [#0] Bob 
TODO [#1] Percival
TODO Tim

Which is what I want.
Now I am using the same file in emacs 29.4 with org mode 9.5.15 and the same sort command gives:
TODO Tim
TODO [#0] Bob 
TODO [#1] Percival

Which is not what I want.
I have been searching and searching for some setting in org mode that might define a sort order but have not been able to find anything.
Any help is appreciated.

I can reproduce this, but I don't know what causes it yet. I'll take a look when I find some time.

@NickD - Thanks very much :)

@NickD - Update - If I comment out "#+PRIORITIES: 0 9 9" in my org file then the sort function does work properly - ie headings without a priority are placed at the bottom of the sort result. However, now I cannot insert new Priorities of 1 to 9 since the default org mode Priority set is A to C.

They should not be: a missing priority cookie should be equivalent to "default priority" which is B by default, so they should appear smack-dab in the middle. The priority calculations are inconsistent in the Org mode code (IIUC). I'm working on a workaround (by defining my own org-priority-get-priority-function), but I'm pretty sure this is a bug which you might want to report with M-x org-submit-bug-report.

org-priority-get-priority-function won't work, because org-sort-entries does not use org-get-priority: it goes back to basics and implements its own method of calculating priorities. It needs to be modified to use org-get-priority I believe.

@NickD  - Thanks for looking into this further. I will report it as a bug. My work-around is to explicitly give each heading a priority.
